# How can I display a 'modal' above mouse position?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table and I try to display a popup when mouse is over a column title
and hide when mouseout

popup behavior is OK but not position

I try to add position based on mouse position but it prevent popup display

**table**

```
<th id="label_id"></th>
```

**popup**

```
<div id="bubble_id" class="bubble" style="display:none;">
   <div class="bubble-text">
      <h4>Definition</h4>
        <hr>
      <p>my definition</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
        $('#label_id').hover(

            // au survol de la souris sur le champ en-tête
            function () {
                $('#bubble_id').removeAttr("style");

                // mouse coordonate
                var left = $(this).offset().left;
                var top = $(this).offset().top;
                // $('#bubble_id').attr("style","left:"+left+"px;"+"top:"+top+"px;");

            }, 

            function () {
                $('#bubble_id').css({"display":"None"});

            }
        );
```

Comment: `$(this).offset().left;` would be related to the element hovered, not the mouse specifically.  To get the mouse position you would need to interrogate the event passed into the hover callback.

Comment: Should the tooltip move with the mouse of be fixed at the TH position on page (say below)? Also, what if you scroll the page and the tooltip positions outside the viewport (even though TH is in viewport)?